# How can CGRectEdge be used to establish the edges of a rectangle?

Tags: ios

CGRectEdge is defined in CGGeometry.h like so:

```
enum CGRectEdge {
  CGRectMinXEdge, CGRectMinYEdge, CGRectMaxXEdge, CGRectMaxYEdge
};
typedef enum CGRectEdge CGRectEdge;
```

and the documentation (in CGGeometry Reference) says that CGRectEdge is "coordinates that establish the edges of a rectangle". So what is setting these values? Or how can these values be set? The individual values are read-only. It sounds potentially useful but I don't see how to use it for anything since I don't see how to set it. Nor how to relate it to a particular rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CGRectEdge enum is used to supply information to calls that divide rectangles into sub-rectangles, these two calls being CGRectDivide in <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h> and MKMapRectDivide in <MapKit/MKGeometry.h>.

```
/* Make two new rectangles, `slice' and `remainder', by dividing `rect' with
a line that's parallel to one of its sides, specified by `edge' -- either
`CGRectMinXEdge', `CGRectMinYEdge', `CGRectMaxXEdge', or
`CGRectMaxYEdge'. The size of `slice' is determined by `amount', which
 measures the distance from the specified edge. */

void CGRectDivide(CGRect rect, CGRect *slice, CGRect *remainder,
    CGFloat amount, CGRectEdge edge);

void MKMapRectDivide(MKMapRect rect, MKMapRect *slice, MKMapRect *remainder, double amount, CGRectEdge edge) NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 4_0);
```

Comment: Green check because this is the better of 2 similar answers only because it has more information. But both answers miss what was confusing me. From the documentation I thought CGRectEdge somehow specified the coordinates of a rectangle. I now understand that its value simply designates one of the four edges of a rect. It is a numerical code for designating one of the four edges. It doesn't give a coordinate for anything. The wording in the documentation seems wrong. It shouldn't say "coordinates that establish the edges of a rectangle" because it doesn't contain coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

This is primarily used in [CGRectDivide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectDivide) from what I can tell.

You would pass a type of `CGRectEdge` to the parameter `edge`

> An edge value that specifies the side of the rectangle from 
>   which the distance passed in the amount parameter is measured. 
>   CGRectDivide produces a “slice” rectangle that contains the specified
>   edge and extends amount distance beyond it.